# Will ingress traffic to a global service always be handled locally on that node?

Tags: load-balancing, docker-swarm

Assuming you run a service exposed on port 80 in `global` mode, will ingress traffic on port 80 for any given node / host then be handled locally by the instance running on that node?

The alternative would be that Swarm load balances the traffic to one of the running instances, regardless of which node it runs on.

Answer (score 0):

After having experimented a bit with this myself, it appears that this can be achieved with the following configuration.

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: [image]
    ports:
      - target: 80
        published: 80
        protocol: tcp
        mode: host
    deploy:
      mode: global
      endpoint_mode: dnsrr
```

The important parts are :

1. Version must be set to `3.2` for the `ports` section format to be supported.
2. For each exposed port, set `mode` to `host`
3. In the `deploy` section, set `mode` to `global` and `endpoint_mode` to `dnsrr`.

This will expose the service directly on port 80 on each node in the cluster, and traffic will be handled directly by that service.